# Control data usage of Safari and other Web browsers on Mac

Tags: macos, safari, web-browser

I find that Web browsers like Safari tend to consume data even after my Web pages are loaded sufficiently to be browsed/read. May I know why?

As an example, I use TripMode to control the data usage of my apps on my Mac. TripMode allows me to

1. Toggle an option for each app whether I want it to use network data or not.
2. See how much data each app has consumed at some point in time. (Please see TripMode's main site for details on how it works.)

There was once, when I loaded a Google search page or something. Just immediately after the page has loaded, TripMode shows that less than 10 MB has been consumed by Safari alone. I just left the Google Search page on my browser while I used another app (eg. Excel) for a few minutes. I returned to find in horror that suddenly the data consumption by Safari has reached 50 MB. No other page/tab/window on Safari was loading.

I'd like to know why. But more importantly, I'd like to know if there's another app or extension (like TripMode) that can restrict Safari's (and/or other browsers like Chrome or Firefox which I also use) after - page data usage.

Comment: I think you may find that most of the data going back and forth from a web page to Safari is prompted at the other end: the web page you are on.

Comment: ok but that does not exclude the possibility of having the browser restrict the flow of data when needed